# How to export a Mathematica list as a fixed-width text file while preserving sig figs?

Tags: export, wolfram-mathematica, fixed-width, significant-digits

My first question is how would I export my data in a fixed-width format using Mathematica? My second question is how do I preserve the right most 0's.

For instance, I like to save `{{1.12300, 11.12, 111.123},{2.1, 22.123, 222}}` into a text file as

```
1.12300  11.12   111.123
2.10     22.123  222.00
```

In details, if a number has a mantissa with less than 2 digits, it is matched to 2 via zero padding while if it has more than 2 digits in its mantissa, it would preserve it as it is. It is important for me to distinguish `1.12300` from `1.123`. If I use `PaddingForm`, Mathematica would literally save it as `PaddedForm[1.123, {4, 5}]` in a text file.

Comment: it is important to understand that a number such as "11.12" , once keyed in or returned as a result is a machine precision binary represented floating point number, and is no longer "exactly" 1112/100.  You should go to mathematica.stackexchange.com for further info, but do a search there are literally dozens of similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
data = {{1.12300``6, 11.12``3,  111.123``4}, 
        {2.1``2,     22.123``4, 222``2}};

tbl1 = ToString[TableForm[data]];
tbl2 = StringReplace[tbl, "\n\n" -> "\n"]
```

to get

```
1.12300   11.12    111.123
2.1       22.123   222.0
```

If you don't want to enter your data as a set of strings, you need to specify the accuracy of your data using ``` `` ```. See [Numerical Precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html) tutorial by Mathematica.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i am looking for. alternatively, tbl1=ToString[Grid[data]] is also ok.

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve the trailing zeros on numbers such as `1.12300` the data has to be received as a string.  Then it can be processed like so.

```
data = "{{1.12300, 11.12, 111.123}, {2.1, 22.123, 222}}";

(* remove any whitespace *)
d1 = StringReplace[data, " " -> ""];

(* split the lists *)
d2 = StringSplit[StringTake[d1, {3, -3}], "},{"];

(* split the numbers *)
d3 = StringSplit[d2, ","];

(* magnitude of number except zero *)
mag[n_] := Floor[Log[10, Abs[n]]] + 1

(* format accordingly *)
d4 = Map[With[{x = ToExpression[#]},
     Which[x == 0, If[StringLength[#] > 4, #, "0.00"],
      FractionalPart[100 x] == 0,
      ToString@NumberForm[x, {mag[x] + 2, 2},
         ExponentFunction -> (Null &)],
      True, #]] &, d3, {2}];

(* pad output *)
len = Max[StringLength /@ Flatten[d4]] + 2;
d5 = Map[StringPadRight[#, len] &, d4, {2}];
d6 = StringJoin /@ d5;
Export["output.txt", d6];
Import["output.txt"]
```

> ```
> 1.12300  11.12    111.123
> 2.10     22.123   222.00
> ```

Comment: Yes, it does generate that example, but the issue is the fixed-width format must use spaces rather than tabs. Unfortunately, this is a format common in astronomy data. Also, the code would not work properly if I change the first element to 1.12300000.

Comment: @mpourrah No problem to implement fixed-width format if you write the specification.  The padding is interesting - a problem that crops up often.  How should the columns be formatted if the first number is 1.12300000?

Comment: I guess I can find out which element of each column has the most number of characters.

Comment: @mpourrah I have added a method along that line.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
listt = {{1.12300, 11.12, 111.123}, {2.1, 22.123, 222}}

Export["C:/tcdata/list.txt", Flatten /@ listt, "Table"]
```